# Initializing service without injection (angular)

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of services (let's call them "handlers") and one manager (which is also a service). 
I want all handlers to "register" themselves to the manager.
My problem is that no one injects these handlers so they are not being instantiated so the code which registers them is not being called. How can I instantiate the handler without injecting it??

I don't want to inject the handlers to the manager directly because in this case registration gives it more flexibility and makes it more generic.

The code is very simple:

**MANAGER:**

```
    angular.module("MyMain").factory('OperationsManager', function () {

        var handlers = [];

        function OperationsManager() { };

        OperationsManager.prototype.registerHandler = function (handler) {
            handlers.push(handler);
        };

        return new OperationsManager();

    });
})(angular);
```

**HANDLER:**

```
(function (angular) {
    angular.module("MyMain").factory('MyHandler', function (OperationsManager) {

        var Handler = {};
        Handler.prototype.someFunction = function(){

        };


        OperationsManager.registerHandler(Handler);

        return Handler;

    });
})(angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a service in which you inject the `OperationsManager`? Then you can pass the handlers as a parameter and it will take care of registering them to the `OperationsManager`.

```
 yourApp.service('nameHere', ['OperationsManager',
     function(OperationsManager) {

         this.registerHandler = function(handler) {
              OperationsManager.register(handler);
         }
     }
 ])
```

Even if this means that you will have to inject this service somewhere. Something has to be injected. At this point you could take care of registering/unregistering directly in the `OperationsManager`though. Why can't you just call `.registerHandler` wherever you inject the `OperationsManager`?